# Vuejs methods not firing

Tags: jquery, d3.js, vue.js, vuejs2, dagre-d3

When i call a vuejs function from jquery selector it is not firing. I have integrate d3-dagre chart in vue component. when i set a click action for the nodes it is not firing the vuejs methods. In the below getJobid() is not firing. Find the below vue component code and also error in the end.

Vue component:

```
export default {
  name: 'dagView',
  created () {
    console.log('test2')
  },
  mounted () {
     var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({})
     // Create the renderer    
     var render = new dagreD3.render()

     // Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
     var svg = d3.select("svg"),
     inner = svg.append("g")

     // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
     render(inner, g)

     inner.selectAll("g.node")
     .on("click", function(v) {
        console.log("Nodes --> "+ v + " -- "+ g.node(v).label)
        this.nodeId = g.node(v).label
        console.log("Node id -- "+ this.nodeId)
        this.getJobid()
     })
  },
  methods: {
    getJobid: function() {
      console.log('Received NodeId')
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getJobid is not a function
at SVGGElement.eval (DAG.vue?2ccc:180)
at SVGGElement.__onclick (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

Comment: `this.getJobid` is not called anywhere in the code you're showing

Comment: @thanksd updated the code you can verify now

Answer (score 6):

The `this` in the callback for the `on` handler is not referencing the Vue instance. Set a reference outside the handler and use that instead:

```
var self = this 
inner.selectAll("g.node")
  .on("click", function(v) {
    console.log("Nodes --> "+ v + " -- "+ g.node(v).label)
    self.nodeId = g.node(v).label
    console.log("Node id -- "+ this.nodeId)
    self.getJobid()
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works... Can you please help me on this issue also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571853/vuejs-dagre-d3-tooltip-issue/

Answer (score 4):

Better to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that the `this` within your callback refers to the Vue instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem here is that "this.getJobid()" actually is not a function
This is referring to  the current context - in your case

```
inner.selectAll("g.node").on("click", function(v) {
// as we are inside inner.selectAll('g.node') 
// our Vue instance is not what we will find here
..
}
```

The solution is to create a reference to the Vue before the registering of your handler, typically

```
const vm = this;
```

Then you can try

```
vm.getJobid();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inner.selectAll("g.node")
  .on("click", (v) => {
    console.log("Nodes --> " + v + " -- " + g.node(v).label)
    this.nodeId = g.node(v).label
    console.log("Node id -- " + this.nodeId)
    this.getJobid()
  })
```

Comment: You better explain your solution than just posting some anonymous code section. You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).